# C++ Horner's Rule - Recursive Array Implementation

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I've implemented the [Horner's Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method) using arrays as follows.

```
double hornerRule( const double x, const double a[], const int n ) {
    double ans = *a;
    if ( n > 0 ) { ans += x * hornerFunction( x, ++a, n - 1 ); }
    return ans;
}
```

I'm a bit new to the pointer arithmetic and have a few questions:

1. Did I commit any sins? Is there a better way to do it?
2. An analogous implementation uses `std::vector` and avoids passing the array size `n`. What are the pros/cons of these two implementations?

Comment: May be post here code fragment that can be run for example on https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com ?  Also this looks like recursive function and can surely be replaced by single loop.

Comment: watch out for the last iteration

Comment: the pro of the `std::vector` version is that you dont have to worry about sins. it is really not about "sins", but about what is easier to use, less error prone and has a more readable syntax.

Comment: btw using iterators would probably more convenient here, otherwise you would still need to keep track of an index into the vector (or make copies)

Answer (score 0):

With a new C++ compiler the modern way would be to have a std::span or gsl::span parameter. It contains the pointer and the length, sub-arrays can be built from it easily.

Depending on n, it could improve the performance, if you change n to a template parameter. Then the recursion could be unrolled without problems and the compiler could do its optimization magic.

You could do the unrolling by manuelly convertig to a loop, too.

It all depends on your aims. Should the function just work correctly. Or is it performance-critical.